# Replacing words by creating a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a list of words that I want to replace in a dataset:

```
my_dict = {
  "positivi": "positivo",
  "positiva": "positivo",
  "lavori": "lavoro",
  "nuova":"nuovo",
  "nuovi": "nuovo",
  "nuove": "nuovo",
    
}
```

In order to do that, I tried as follows:

```
import nltk

a = df['Title'].str.lower().str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(a)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(1000),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])

df_1 = df_1.Word.replace(my_dict,inplace=True) # the problem is here. This returns an empty df_1

df_1 = df_1[df_1['Word'].str.len()>3]

list_of_words=["dopo","entro","fare","fanno","loro","indietro","insieme","avranno","7115","allo","anche","cosa","dalle","dall","dagli","dentro","secondo","sempre",'siamo','sarà','sarebbe','troppi','tutti','verso','sotto','stesso','sulle','2018','ogni','oggi','nell','nelle','niente','queste','meno','alle','sulla','contro','come','per', 'della','sono','dell','solo','quali','quasi','ecco','ancora']

df_1 = df_1.groupby(['Word'], as_index=False).sum()
df_1 = df_1[~ df_1.Word.str.contains('|'.join(list_of_words), case=False)]

df_1.sort_values(by=['Frequency'], ascending=False).to_csv("path/my_dict.csv")
```

However it does not replace anything in the text. For example:

```
Title 

Una notizia positiva dopo tanto tempo 
Quali lavori svolgi?
```

I should expect to create a new dictionary in csv with the replaced words and the new frequency. But actually I print the same, old list.

Can you please tell what it is wrong within my code?

Some sample of data

```
0      Torna la domenica al museo: l'iniziativa positiva...
1      Torino, lettera di un boss ai giovani: “Non f...
2      Gli studenti italiani non capiscono i lavori...
3      Offerte nuovi lavori: le principali posizion...
                             ...
```

Comment: The error is at this step: `df_1 = df_1.Word.replace(my_dict,inplace=True)` . This returns an empty df_1 as it gives me an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess that the issue is inplace=True.  That will update the dateframe inplace and return nothing.

I don't know if there are other problems and I can't test without sample data for df.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

import pandas as pd

data = (['Torna la domenica al museo: l\'iniziativa positiva',
'Torino, lettera di un boss ai giovani: “Non f...',
'Gli studenti italiani non capiscono i lavori...',
'Offerte nuovi lavori: le principali posizion...'])

my_dict = {
  "positivi": "positivo",
  "positiva": "positivo",
  "lavori": "lavoro",
  "nuova":"nuovo",
  "nuovi": "nuovo",
  "nuove": "nuovo",
    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Title'])        

a = df['Title'].str.lower().str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(a)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(1000),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])

df_1.Word = df_1.Word.replace(my_dict)

df_1 = df_1[df_1['Word'].str.len()>3]

list_of_words=["dopo","entro","fare","fanno","loro","indietro","insieme","avranno","7115","allo","anche","cosa","dalle","dall","dagli","dentro","secondo","sempre",'siamo','sarà','sarebbe','troppi','tutti','verso','sotto','stesso','sulle','2018','ogni','oggi','nell','nelle','niente','queste','meno','alle','sulla','contro','come','per', 'della','sono','dell','solo','quali','quasi','ecco','ancora']

df_1 = df_1.groupby(['Word'], as_index=False).sum()
df_1 = df_1[~ df_1.Word.str.contains('|'.join(list_of_words), case=False)]

df_1.sort_values(by=['Frequency'], ascending=False).to_csv("64671179.csv")
```

the csv file contains:

```
,Word,Frequency
6,lavoro,2
0,boss,1
9,nuovo,1
15,torino,1
14,studenti,1
13,principali,1
12,posizion,1
11,positivo,1
10,offerte,1
8,museo,1
```

Comment: Thanks B. Bogart. How can I rename the columns Word? If I do not use inplace, I cannot call it after.

Comment: Right, sorry.  I've updated the answer with one posibility.  The other is to use inplace=True but not assign it to df_1.

Comment: Thanks B.Bogart. Unfortunately it seems still not updating the csv file with the words redefined in dictionary. It seems that I am not updating the df_1. Do you spot any inconsistencies? I cannot see anything :(

Comment: Can you provide sample data?  It would be much easier to test with something to test on.

Comment: I provided some data. Please see the question. Thanks for your help B.Bogart

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I am getting as the csv output.  I'll also add all of my code in case there is something outside the example I am doing differently.

Comment: Thank you so much B.Bogart. Your code seems working fine. Unfortunately mine it is still not. I just replaced the dataset name (which is called live) and the name of dict (which is called live_dict) and kept all your code. The csv is still the old one though I have used to_csv("64671179.csv"). I really appreciated your help. Thanks a lot